# Javascript array property in a class only returned if its called from a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const Color = {
  RED: 'red',
  GREEN: 'green',
  BLUE: 'blue',

  values: [this.RED, this.GREEN, this.BLUE],

  allValues() {
    return [this.RED, this.GREEN, this.BLUE]
  }
}

console.log(Color.values); // [undefined, undefined, undefined]
console.log(Color.allValues()); // ["red", "green", "blue"]
```

I recently started learning about javascript and this is tripping me up, I would consider making it work by wrapping it up in a function hacky and would really like to avoid doing that. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "You can't reference an object during initialization when using object literal syntax. You need to reference the object after it is created." See the link above.

Comment: [Great Article to understand Javascript Context/This](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible within an object literal. While creating the Object instance from the literal `this` is not yet available. You can create and instantaneous use something to initialize the `values`, or use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) for the `values` property (see [@James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82586/james) answer for that) though:

```js
// initialization
const Color = {
  RED: 'red',
  GREEN: 'green',
  BLUE: 'blue',
  init() {
    this.values = [this.RED, this.GREEN, this.BLUE];
    return this;
  }
}.init();

console.log(Color.values);
```

Just for fun: if you want to rule out the use of `this` completely, this (pun intended;) would be es20xx alternatives:

```js
const Color = Object.entries({
  RED: 'red',
  GREEN: 'green',
  BLUE: 'blue'})
  .reduce( (o, [key, value]) => 
    ( o.values.push(value), {...o, [key]: value} ), {values: []} );
  
console.log(Color.values);

// Or using this utility method
const objWithValues = o => 
    ({...o, values: Object.entries(o).map(([key, value]) => value) });
const Color2 = objWithValues({
    RED: 'red',
    GREEN: 'green',
    BLUE: 'blue'});

console.log(Color2.values);
```

Comment: Hmm the initialize approach is an interesting one, it solves the problem of creating an array everytime the values() func is called. Since i am new to JS what is the norm here? Is it acceptable to use getters in these scenarios since there is a built in way to do this?

Comment: Personally I'd use a getter in this situation. Only in more complex situations or with huge data sizes the initialization may be more efficient and/or convenient.

Comment: Hmm... seems like this answer was edited to basically include mine, oh well.

Comment: @James: sorry, I constructed my answer is steps

Comment: Not sure I buy that tbh, your first answer was a definite "this can't be done" and offered the first solution as a workaround, to then minutes later "you can use a getter" - surely you seen my answer after you posted? It was posted at pretty much the same time. It's irrelevant now but not a fan of the whole reworking answers when it's already been suggested.

Comment: My answers often are not final in one go, I try to come up with alternatives if can think of them. Sometimes it takes a bit of time to try it out. In this case I offered 4 alternatives, one of which is using a getter. And no, the getter version was not specifically copied from your anwer - but hey, you don't _have_ to buy that.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question, this can be done via a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

```
const Color = {
  RED: 'red',
  GREEN: 'green',
  BLUE: 'blue',

  get values() {
    return [this.RED, this.GREEN, this.BLUE]
  }
}
...
console.log(Color.values); // ['red', 'green', 'blue']
```

Comment: How is this any different than OP's allValues method

Comment: @Isaac because syntactically the OP gets the desired behaviour of calling the property and not the a function.